# Dynamically Accessing SwiftData Parameter

Tags: swiftui, parameters, observable, swift-data

I'm facing a challenge in Swift and seeking advice. I have a class `Results` that contains various parameters, and it's a SwiftData Model. Therefore I want to change it directly, as it is observed then. Now, I want to dynamically access one of these parameters based on a string.

Here's a simplified example of my code:

```
@Model
class Results {
    var parameter1: Bool = false
    var parameter2: Bool = false
    var parameter3: Bool = false
    // More parameters...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let instanceOfResults = Results()
    let parameterName = "parameter1"

    var body: some View {
   
        instanceOfResults[keyPath: "\(parameterName)"] = false  // The issue is here 
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> "Value of type 'Results' has no subscripts"

and I'm not sure how to access the parameter directly when the name is dynamic. Does anyone have an idea or approach on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`PersistentModel` has both `getValue(forKey:)` and `setValue(forKey:to:)` functions that takes a `KeyPath` as the key. So if it's ok to work with key paths rather than strings then what you want can be accomplished.

```
let parameterKey: KeyPath<Results, Bool> = \.parameter1

let parameterValue = instanceOfResults.getValue(forKey: parameterKey)

instanceOfResults.setValue(forKey: parameterKey, to: false)
```

The key path property needs to be declared with a type and in this example it's easy since all `Results` properties are `Bool` but if they are of different types you need to look into creating generic functions or overloading functions or different properties per type to handle all the model properties.